# how to use an if statement in update query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I wanted to use if statement in Oracle update. Below is the condition that i wanted to achieve and i will not be able to use PL/SQL. I wanted to achieve the below result using update statement.

```
if code like'0001'  then
   code ='0001'
elsif code like'01' then 
   code = 'ok'
else 
   code = 'NOTOK'
end
```

I tried the below update statement not exactly what i need but just trying a simple update using case..

```
UPDATE tblname
SET CODE =  CASE
              WHEN CODE not like '01% OR CODE not like '0001% THEN
                'NOTOK'
            END
```

Comment: are you trying to update `code` or `desc` column ? OK logically should be `desc`

Comment: Well, Barbaros is right, that's quite confusing. In your pseudo code you have `code`, `'001'`, `'ok'`, and `'NOTOK'`, and in your update statement there is `DESC` and `'DIRECT'` instead.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros and Thorsten for looking into it, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to use

```
UPDATE tblname 
   SET "DESC" = CASE 
                WHEN SUBSTR(CODE,1,2)='01' THEN 
                     'OK' 
                WHEN SUBSTR(CODE,1,4)='0001' THEN 
                     SUBSTR(CODE,1,4)
                ELSE
                     'NOT OK'
                END
```

`desc` is a reserved keyword. So, there cannot be a column name unquoted.

Comment: Thank you so much Barbaros.  I was struggling to find the solution for 2 hours..

Answer (score 2):

You can apply multiple `WHEN ... THEN`. The first match wins, so it works just like your `if / else if`.

```
UPDATE tblname 
SET code = CASE WHEN code LIKE '0001%' THEN '0001'
                WHEN code LIKE '01%' THEN 'ok'
                ELSE 'NOTOK'
           END;
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, I just found and i tried and it worked too. Thanks for your support.